# Rollup minify classnames

Tags: rollupjs, svelte-3, rollup-plugin-postcss

Is there any rollup.js plugins which allow to obfuscate / mangle CSS class names? I haven't found anything, except this one for webpack: https://github.com/sndyuk/mangle-css-class-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss#css-modules). As per the readme, configuration options for the `modules` property are passed through to [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules#generating-scoped-names).
Using the `generateScopedName` property you're able to set the format of the class name:

```js
generateScopedName: "[hash:base64:8]",
```

There are more examples in the postcss-modules readme including how to generate the name dynamically. Note that you are responsible for ensuring that the names are unique enough to not clash.

The full rollup config would look something like:

```js
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
... // other imports

export default {
  ... // rest of config
  plugins: [
    ... // other plugins
    postcss({
      ...
      modules: {
        generateScopedName: "[hash:base64:8]",
      },
      autoModules: true,
    }),
    ...
  ],
};
```

Then something like:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
/* styles.module.css */
```

```
import STYLES from './styles.module.css';

...

// Use the style however
<div className={STYLES.parent}> 
  ...
</div>
```

Ends up looking like:

```css
.xSgFDOB2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="xSgFDOB2">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that `autoModules: true` assumes your style files are named like `something.module.scss`  If the do not have `.module.` in your style file names, for example `my-component.scss`, then generatedScopedName fails silently, the class names are not truncated, and "undefined" gets inserted in your compiled javascript.  To fix this, set autoModules to false.  https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss/issues/296#issuecomment-774040297

Comment: @Sam, thank you for the response. Will this trick work with Sveltekit?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was adding `generateScopedName` to `modules` and setting `autoModules: false,`

```
    postcss({
        extensions: ['.scss'],
        modules: {
            generateScopedName: `[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]`,
        },
        autoModules: false,
        use: ['sass'],
    }),
```